# Can a UITableView cell be atomic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a situation where I create a UITableView that has a frame:

```
CGRectMake(0, 88, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];
```

The height for each cell is set as 128. I am re-using cells to optimize performance. As I try to do this, only cells that are completely visible to the user are getting loaded. The UI elements within partially visible cells remain blank.

Is there a way to display `UITableViewCell` atomically? That is, a cell should either be displayed in its entirety or not displayed at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to allow partially drawn cells? For all standard situations, they are essential for the correct feel of the table view, as they give a good hint that scrolling makes sense.

Comment: @Eiko Partially drawn cells are not displaying the UIButton's title that is in that particular cell. (Because it is not loaded into memory).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to monitor scrolling and scan all of the visible cells to determine if they are fully visible and use that to determine if the `contentView` is `hidden` or not.

Note that the scroll view won't be scrolled every time the rows are changed. So, you should add your show / hide logic to a new method and trigger it when the scroll view tells your controller that it moved and also whenever you add / remove rows.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether this works, if the table view changes because of insertions/deletions of entries.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, the scroll view delegate may not be triggered but the same functionality can be run in these other cases

Comment: you should add this to your answer. Beside this it is not nice to have such code spreaded over the sources. Maybe it would be a better approach to customize the drawing.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad fair point, I've added a bit to the answer. The code shouldn't be spread around, there should just be a few methods that change things and trigger the processing.